# Number of injective functions between sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} a B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}. How many injective functions f : A → B exist such that f({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) ⊇ {1, 2, 3}?

**My approach:**

Since I have to choose 3 positions from  **f({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})** which would be set **{1, 2, 3}** then I it would be **$\binom{5}{3}$**.
Then I have **3!** ways of filling them with the set **{1,2,3}**.
Lastly, for the last two i have six options which would be **$\binom{6}{2}$**.

And that would then equal to **$\binom{5}{3}$** **$\binom{6}{2}$** 3! = 900

Is this correct or did I make a mistake?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems too small.  Even we add the further restriction that $f(\{1,2,3\})=\{1,2,3\}$ ($6$ ways to do that), we'd then have $6$ choices for $f(4)$, $5$ for $f(5)$, $4$ for $f(6)$ and $3$ for $f(7)$ making the total for this more restrictive class of functions:  $6\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3=2160$.  Of course, the answer to your question is a lot larger than this. (Hint:  it can be computed along the same lines I followed to count the more restrictive case).

Comment: Your estimate looks far too small.  Your ${5 \choose 3}3!$ deals with the condition, but that leaves four remaining elements of $A$ to be injected into the remaining six elements of $B$.  You may be out by a factor of $24$

Answer (score 2):

You're mostly right:

There are $5\choose 3$ ways to select the elements to map into $\{1, 2, 3\}$, and for each choice there are $3!$ ways to map them. After that, you have 4 elements left to map into $\{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, and these 4 elements are uniquely determined by your earlier choice of the first 3 elements (the ones being mapped into $\{1, 2, 3\}$). This second mapping can be done in $6!/(6-4)!$ ways. So, the final number of such functions is
$${5\choose 3}\cdot 3! \cdot \frac{6!}{2!}=21600$$

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the catch, edited. x2 haha